# Does $\int\min(1,\|x\|)<\infty$ imply $\int\left|e^{{\rm i}\langle x,\:x'\rangle}-1-{\rm i}\langle x,x'\rangle1_{\overline B_1(0)}(x)\right|<\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, levy-processes

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $\lambda$ be a measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ with $$\int\min(1,\|x\|_E)\:\lambda({\rm d}x)<\infty.\tag1$$ Are we able to conclude $$\int\left|\underbrace{e^{{\rm i}\langle x,\:x'\rangle}-1-{\rm i}\langle x,x'\rangle1_{\overline B_1(0)}(x)}_{=:\:K(x,\:x')}\right|\:\lambda({\rm d}x)<\infty\tag2$$ for all $x'\in E'$?

$(1)$ is clearly equivalent to $$\int_{\overline B_1(0)}\|x\|_E^2\:\lambda({\rm d}x)<\infty\tag3$$ and $$\lambda\left({\overline B_1(0)}^c\right)<\infty\tag4.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. The integral over the ball is finite becasue of the standard inequality $|e^{it}-1-it|\leq \frac {t^{2}} 2$ valid for all real $t$ (and the inequality $|\langle x, x \rangle'|\leq \|x\| \|x'\|$) and  the integral over the complement is finite  because $|e^{it}-1|\leq 2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is the same true if we replace $(1)$ by the weaker assumption $\int\min(1,\|x\|_E^2)\:\lambda({\rm d}x)<\infty$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, by the same proof.